# Showing field even when Left join give a null

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 3 tables : `product`, `order_details`, `orders`.

I want to join them in one query showing all products that a user have bought.

Here is my code :

```
SELECT products.id AS id,
      products.kode  AS kode,
      products.sub_kode AS sub_kode,
      products.nama AS nama,
      products.barcode AS barcode,
      products.harga AS harga,
      IFNULL(products.keterangan_kemasan, ' ') AS keterangan_kemasan,
      IFNULL(products.keterangan_ukuran ,' ') AS keterangan_ukuran,
      SUM(IFNULL(order_details.jumlah_pesanan_akhir,0)) AS jumlah,
      IFNULL(order_details.jumlah_pesanan_akhir,0) AS jumlah_beli,
      orders.idmember AS member
    FROM products LEFT JOIN (orders,order_details)
    ON (orders.id = order_details.idorder
      AND order_details.product_kode = products.kode
      AND order_details.product_subkode = products.sub_kode)
    WHERE products.nama LIKE '%asdu%'
      AND IFNULL(orders.idmember, 21376) = 21376     
    GROUP BY products.kode, products.sub_kode
    ORDER BY IFNULL(order_details.jumlah_pesanan_akhir,0) DESC,
      products.nama ASC
    LIMIT 30;
```

What is happening is when a costumer never buy that item, the item will not be displayed.   Meanwhile, I want them to be displayed.

If I remove this from the query,

```
AND IFNULL(orders.idmember, 21376) = 21376
```

All will be show well. But it will show other persons order history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand, you want all the products that looks like `%asdu%`, and you want to know if the customer `21376` have bought them.

The id of the user must be a part of the LEFT JOIN clause, else it will be filtered away.

```
SELECT products.id AS id,
      products.kode  AS kode,
      products.sub_kode AS sub_kode,
      products.nama AS nama,
      products.barcode AS barcode,
      products.harga AS harga,
      IFNULL(products.keterangan_kemasan, ' ') AS keterangan_kemasan,
      IFNULL(products.keterangan_ukuran ,' ') AS keterangan_ukuran,
      SUM(IFNULL(order_details.jumlah_pesanan_akhir,0)) AS jumlah,
      IFNULL(order_details.jumlah_pesanan_akhir,0) AS jumlah_beli,
      orders.idmember AS member
    FROM products 
        LEFT JOIN order_details
            ON order_details.product_kode = products.kode
            AND order_details.product_subkode = products.sub_kode
        LEFT JOIN orders
            ON orders.id = order_details.idorder
            AND orders.idmember = 21376
    WHERE products.nama LIKE '%asdu%'
    GROUP BY products.kode, products.sub_kode
    ORDER BY IFNULL(order_details.jumlah_pesanan_akhir,0) DESC,
      products.nama ASC
    LIMIT 30;
```

I have rewrite the joins to be clear on what is being join with what.

Comment: thanks alot, i have not know that join can be like that, i mean, i never do the orders.idmember = 21376 thing... :D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rethink the need to limit it to 1 query. As you have noticed, it's difficult to get it to do what you want.

Two or three queries is ALOT easier to understand. You are working on it now, bit if you look back in a year, this will look jibberish. Also, if someone else needs to correct this, they would have a difficult time.

My suggestion:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=123
    // With that result:
    SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id=$user['id']
        // While this loops:
        SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE orderid=$orders['id']
```

Might even be faster for the database, joins are slow, especially with large tables. It will lock tables which makes it slow for other users. And the `GROUP BY`'s dont help either